# Print specific lines(Words/numbers) from csv file

Tags: java, csv

Lets say I have CSV file like this:

```
Football Contest blabla bla,,,,,,, 
Team number1,Team number2,Points team1,Points team2,Red cards 
Sweden,France,1,2," 
Sweden,Brazil,3,5,2 
Sweden,Germany,2,2,3 
Sweden,Spain,3,5,"
```

And in this file I only want to print out the matches that got red cards. So in this example I would like to print:
Sweden - Brazil = 2  Sweden - Germany = 3

This is my current code, and Im stuck how to move on.

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String lines = br.readLine();
    String result[] = lines.split(",");
    do{
        System.out.println();
    }while((lines = br.readLine()) != null); 

    //String result[] = lines.split(",");
    //System.out.println(result[1]);

    br.close();

}catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found : "+ file.toString());
}catch (IOException e ){
    System.out.println("Unable to read file: "+ file.toString());
}
```

EDIT I got helped with:

```
 while (line != null) {
        String result[] = line.split(",");
        if (result.length == 5) { //red cards present?
            System.out.println(result[0] + " - " + result[1] + " " + result[4]);
        }
        line = br.readLine(); //read next
    }
```

But the problem I have now is that it still prints all because of the " in the csv file. Why cant I do something like this?

```
    if (result[4] == "1,2,3,4,5" ){
System.out.println(result[0] + " - " + result[1] + " " + result[4]);
}
```

Comment: read line by line, then line.split(","), analize values and output what you need

Comment: To correctly parse CSV, use a library such as [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).  Otherwise you will be reinventing a tokenizer and parser.  All suggestions to use regular expressions and/or split() will produce fragile code that does not handle all valid representations of CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Your try-catch block should look like this:

```
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String result[] = line.split(",");
            if (result.length == 5 && result[4].matches("[0-9]")) { //red cards present? 
                System.out.println(result[0] + " - " + result[1] + " " + result[4]);
            }
            line = br.readLine(); //read next
        }
        //close readers
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found : " + file.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read file: " + file.toString());
    }
```

If there are trailing whitespaces in your file, you have to trim the String first: `result[4].trim().matches("[0-9]")` or use another regex: `result[4].matches("\\d\\s")`

Comment: This got me in the right direction. Can I make so the "if"  looking for a number at that certain spot instead of checking length?

Comment: @Dolle Now I understand what you meant. See my edited code: Check length first, then check for a digit. If this was helpful, please mark the answer as such by clicking on the upper arrow.

Comment: @ WürgspaßIf I want red cards present more than 0-9? I cant get it work if I its like 13 red cards. Because [0-13] didnt quite hit the mark

Comment: @Dolle well, that is not part of your original question. "[0-9]" means any **one** digit from 0 to 9. Since there is not a **single** digit like "13" [0-13] could not work. For more than one digit (and allowing white spaces) use this: `result[4].matches("\\d*\\s*")`

Answer (score 0):

If you the index of red card and it looks like Integer, Then see for that index is integer or not if Yes the print 0,1 and 4
    **index[0]=Team number1
    index[1]=Team number2
    index[4]=red cards**

Answer (score 0):

> Why cant I do something like this?
>
> ```
>    if (result[4] == "1,2,3,4,5" ){
> ```

The problem with this is `==` tests for identity: it will compare if the *reference* in `result[4]` is the same *reference* as the constant in your source code. That expression will always be false.  You need to check for equality, not identity:

```
if (Objects.equals(result[4], "1,2,3,4,5")) {
```

or

```
if (result[4] != null && result[4].equals("1,2,3,4,5")) {
```

or

```
if ("1,2,3,4,5".equals(result[4])) {
```

Note that `Objects.equals()` was (finally) added to the Java standard library in Java 8.  Without it, you must guard against a NullPointerException before you call the .equals() method on an object.  Traditionally I have preferred the last version because invoking the method on the string literal means I can be assured it is never null and will just work.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this**
public class HelloWorld{

```
 public static void main(String []args){

String str1=  "Sweden,Brazil,3,5,4"; 
String str2="Sweden,Germany,2,2,3"; 
String str3="Football Contest blabla bla,,,,,,,";

String result1[]=str1.split(",");
String result2[]=str2.split(",");
String result3[]=str3.split(",");

      if(result1.length>=5){
          System.out.print(result1[0]+"-"+result1[1]+"="+result1[4]); 
          System.out.println();
      }
       if(result2.length>=5){
          System.out.print(result2[0]+"-"+result2[1]+"="+result2[4]); 
          System.out.println();
      }
       if(result3.length>=5){
          System.out.print(result3[0]+"-"+result3[1]+"="+result3[4]); 
          System.out.println();
      }




 }
```

}

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
do {
     if (result[4]  instanceof Integer) { 
         System.out.print(result[0]+"="+result[1]+"="+result[4])
     }     
} while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null);
```

Comment: Are you sure? `if (result[4] instanceof Integer)` will always be `false`.